# UIApplication sharedApplication openURL

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate, uiapplicationdelegate, openurl

I have a hybrid app which has an iOS obj-c case proj which only have AppDelegate class, all the other logic are developed in the hybrid-app.

there are multiple usage of openURL in hybrid app. 
what I need:

1) handle the openURL delegate in case iOS app(AppDelegate)

2) can I change all the URLs? (in AppDelegate)

3) can I override `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL]`

Comment: You want to implement open URL login in your hybrid app or on the native generated code?

Answer (score 1):

Register Custom URL scheme for your app

Use Custom URL to invoke your app

Here is the delegate method in your app delegate that gets called and you can parse down to read the different URLs and invoke different functionality in the app.

```
- (BOOL) application : (UIApplication*) app openURL : (NSURL*) url options : (NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey, id>*) options {

         //Parse the URL and invoke the necessary modules or webpages 

        return true;

    }
```

Please go through this tutorial [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html).It'll give you the complete idea.

Hope this helps.

---

Update

1) handle the openURL delegate in case iOS app(AppDelegate)

Yes , it can be handled in the aforementioned delegate

2) can I change all the URLs? (in AppDelegate)

Yes, you can read the custom URL scheme and change the URL and invoke the URL in your webview

3) can I override [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL]

If you mean reading the invoked URL in the delegate method , then Yes

Comment: I want to handle the URL before it exits the app and open the url from the original app

Comment: thats why I want to override openURL in uiapplication

Comment: You mean to say there are URLs in your hybrid app and when it is clicked you want to capture the URL and change the URL and then call the URL ?

Comment: Can you explain me what you are trying to achieve step by step with one scenario so that I can understand better and help you with that.

Comment: I found a solution, I created a subclass of UIApplication and override openURL method

Comment: Great ! Post the solution as answer so that it'll be helpful for others and I would suggest you to change your question a bit to inlcude more information so that it'll be useful for anyone who's seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to create a subclass of UIApplication and override openURL method

**Header File**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Application : UIApplication

@end
```

**implementation file**

```
 #import "Application.h"


@implementation Application

- (void)openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKey,id> *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completion
{

    //DO what Ever Here befor called supoer

    [super openURL:url options:options completionHandler:completion];

}

@end
```

Additional modification needed in main.m file

UIApplication should be modified, so the subclass is put instead of general system

**main.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Application.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([Application class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Subclassing `UIApplication` is very rarely necessary and not recommended. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication "Most apps don’t need to subclass UIApplication. Instead, use an app delegate to manage interactions between the system and the app.".